# Asynchronous BinaryReader and BinaryWriter in .Net?

Tags: .net, f#

I'd like to read and write bytes and structured value types, asynchronously, without having to worry about decoders and byte-shifting: is there something out there that would allow me to do that?

Comment: how about `Stream.BeginRead` etc?

Comment: That's on Stream, not BinaryReader and BinaryWriter.

Comment: you want to read/write bytes; you don't need a `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` for that - they are indeed actively unhelpful towards that end.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that I also want to read structured value types such as Int64 etc.

Comment: My guess is a BinaryReader/BinaryWriter with async methods would be too granular for most cases, and performance would suffer as a consequence.

Comment: Couldn't a ReadInt16() : Async<int16> on the reader, simply fetch a 512-chunk of array from the underlying stream? Why would one have to only read the minimal amount from the stream - in this case it wouldn't affect performance badly, would it?

Answer (score 13):

It's not possible with `BinaryReader` or `BinaryWriter`. You could read concurrently from the underlying `BaseStream`, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.basestream.aspx) states the following:

> Using the underlying stream while reading or while using the BinaryReader can cause data loss and corruption. For example, the same bytes might be read more than once, bytes might be skipped, or character reading might become unpredictable.

Therefore the only way is to roll your own implementation. But the benefit of doing that is debatable. Marco Greg from Microsoft added the following comment to the blog article [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx):

> Jon: The reason that the BinaryReader/Writer do not have XxxAsync methods is that the methods on those types typically read/write only very few bytes from an underlying stream that has been previously opened. In practice, the data is frequently cached and the time required to fetch the data from the underlying source is typically so small that it is not worth it doing it asynchronously.
>
> Notably, there are some methods on these types that in some circumstances may transfer larger amounts of data (e.g. ReadString). Further down the line, Async versions for those methods may or may not be added, but it is unlikely it will happen in the immediate future.
>
> In general, you should only consider Async IO methods if the amount of data you are reading is significant (at least several hundreds or thousands of bytes), or if you are accessing a resource for the first time (e.g. a first read from a file may require to spin up the disk even if you are reading one byte).

This sounds reasonable. If you do need a solution there are several workarounds apart from rolling your own `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter`. You can run it in a separate thread (which can be inefficient) or if you're willing to change the file format or wire protocol you could use this pattern (pseudo-code):

```
//read packet length
await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
var packetLength=convertToInt(buffer);

//read complete packet asynchronously
await stream.ReadAsync(buffer,packetLength);

//process packet with BinaryReader
using(var br=new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
  //...
}
```

Please note that this pattern is only useful if the complete buffer easily fits in memory and that performance might suffer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FileStream`, make sure you call the constructor properly so it enables async and has a large enough buffer.

```
var buffer = new byte[2048];

using var r = new FileStream(
                  Path,
                  FileMode.Open, 
                  FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                  FileShare.None, 
                  2048000, 
                  FileOptions.Asynchronous);

await r.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 2048);
await r.Writesync(buffer);
```

Now that you have a byte array you can have three options to convert them to objects:

- use [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netcore-3.1)
- use `BinaryFormatter` and `MemoryStream`
- write your own custom logic

Answer (score 2):

I've created versions of those classes that are async: https://github.com/ronnieoverby/AsyncBinaryReaderWriter

Example usage:

```
async Task Main()
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using var writer = new AsyncBinaryWriter(ms);
    await writer.WriteAsync("today is: ");
    await writer.WriteAsync(DateTime.Today.Ticks);
    await writer.FlushAsync();

    ms.Position = 0;

    using var reader = new AsyncBinaryReader(ms);
    var preamble = await reader.ReadStringAsync();
    var payload = new DateTime(await reader.ReadInt64Async());

    Console.WriteLine(preamble + payload);
}
```

All of the same read/write methods present on the BCL binary reader/writer classes are present.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Your implementation looks like it is what I need. However, I see no documentation about how to use it or considerations for when it might cause blocking or impact on performance. I also see issues opened for multiple years. Is there any hope that more will happen with this?

Comment: @DavidBowser In general, if you are familiar with the synchronous plain-old binary reader/writer classes _and_ you know you need async operations (and all of the potential pitfalls that come with that) I don't expect there's much documentation needed. As for the opened issues, I have no interest in addressing them, but will be happy to review and merge pull requests.