# C# Cancel the previous IO save Task when starting a new one

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, io, task

I'm trying to make a task to save data asynchronously for my achievement system. This task is run once every 1 minute from the main code, but it can also be run at any other time.

---

**I want to achieve these goals:**

1. Only one save task can run at a time.
2. As soon as a save request arrives, the previous save task, if it exists, should be cancelled.
3. The new task should start after the previous task has completed its cancellation and the resources of the previous task have been cleared.
4. If there is a save task in the queue that has not yet started, a new task should not be created.
5. When requesting to start a task, it should be possible to wait for the task to complete on the main thread. If a new task has not been created because the previous one has not started yet, then you need to wait for the completion of the task that has not yet started.
6. After the execution of the current task, all the resources that it used should be released.

---

So far I've tried different options, and this is the last one:

**Data Warehouse and Save Task Scheduler:**

```cs
public class AchievementSaveTask {
    private bool cancelled;
    private Task currentSource;

    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, AchievementData> aDatas;

    public AchievementSaveTask() => aDatas = MouseAchievementFile.Read();

    public async Task StartWriting() {
        await CancelWrite();

        currentSource = Task.Run(() => MouseAchievementFile.Write(aDatas, cancelled));
        await currentSource;
        currentSource.Dispose();
        currentSource = null;
    }

    public async Task CancelWrite() {
        if (currentSource != null) {
            cancelled = true;
            await currentSource;
            cancelled = false;
            currentSource.Dispose();
            currentSource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class for writing data to a file:**

```cs
public class MouseAchievementFile {
    private const string FOLDER = "MouseWorld/Achievement", FILE = "achievements.mdat";

    public static void Write(ConcurrentDictionary<int, AchievementData> data, in bool cancelled = false) {
        var pathDir = Combine(Main.SavePath, FOLDER);
        if (!Directory.Exists(pathDir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDir);
        //Execution stops somewhere here, why?
        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Combine(pathDir, FILE), FileMode.Create))) {
            foreach ((_, var value) in data) {
                var datas = value.GetRawData();
                foreach (var currData in datas) {
                    if (!CheckWrite(bw, currData, cancelled)) {
                        datas.Clear();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                datas.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool CheckWrite(BinaryWriter bw, string source, in bool cancelled) {
        if (!cancelled) {
            bw.Write(source);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            bw.Flush();
            bw.Close();
            bw.Dispose();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Extension method:**

```cs
public static void HandleException(this Task source, Action<Exception> exceptionHandler) {
    source.ContinueWith(t => exceptionHandler(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

**Call:**

```cs
if (wait) achievementSaveTask.StartWriting().Wait();
else achievementSaveTask.StartWriting().HandleException(t => MWMod.Instance.Logger.WarnFormat("MAChievementManager.SaveAchievements() - WARNING! Could not save dict. Exception: {0}\r{1}", t.Message, t.StackTrace));
```

#### UPDATE:

After some experimentation, I tried changing my code to use async-await. And although it worked in a console application (outputting a string to the console), in the real case, where I need to write a file, the program freezes. Empirically, I found out that this happens approximately when creating a BinaryWriter. And I guess there is a deadlock going on.

As they said in the comments, BinaryWriter is not suitable for asynchronous writing, but it is important for me to write data in binary form and I do not understand how I can refuse it.

In this regard, the following questions arise:

1. Why does the freeze occur?
2. Can I avoid the problem by using StreamWriter?
3. Can I use StreamWriter to write data in binary form? (The goal is to get the output file unreadable and uneditable using text editors)

Comment: `BinaryWriter` is not async-compatible and cannot use `CancellationToken` is there any reaosn why you are using it?

Comment: @Charlieface No, there is no particular reason for me to use the token. I've tried many options, and the cancellation token is just an echo of some previous option. I am ready to delete it at any time, I only need the ability to pass the actual variable to cancel the write process. About BinaryWriter... I don't really understand how asynchrony works in c#, but I write line by line, and I can stop it at any time by closing the write stream. So I decided to pass a variable that signals that the task has been cancelled. Maybe I'm missing something, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No I mean why you are using `BinaryWriter` at all, it's basically deprecated? CancellationToken` is the correct way to handle this, just `BinaryWriter` does not accept or handle it

Comment: @Charlieface To be honest, I'm a little confused by this fact. Why is it deprecated? I did not know about this and did not find information. The key aspect is that I want to write data that cannot be edited through a text document. This way I protect myself from standard users who want to fix the achievements. I can just as well use any other method instead of BinaryWriter, but I'm afraid I haven't come up with anything better. If there is a better solution, I will gladly accept it

Comment: Sorry you're right, not deprecated, but there are no async methods https://stackoverflow.com/q/10315316/14868997 I just don't get what you gain in this case over just using `StreamWriter`, not sure what you are trying to protect from. `StreamWriter` has async methods, and you can pass a `CancellationToken` in.

Comment: @Charlieface Maybe it's my endless typos using a translator. I'm sorry if that's the case. I meant that I want to write the data in binary form so that they cannot be read and edited using text editors. Can I do this using StreamWriter for example? Strings are used as input, but I do not know how many, there can be from 2 to infinity, so I cannot predetermine the buffer. In addition, the size of the input data can be very large. There are several lines for one achievement, but if you count for all achievements, this can be an indefinitely large number

Comment: Leaving aside BinaryWriter, for now I've tried a new solution using async-await. Since I've worked in java before, I've never experienced this and feel like I've gone down a rabbit hole. At the moment, I tried this option in a console application so that I have access to debugging. Once I test this solution in an actual project, I'll edit the question and maybe things will clear up a bit